# Service broker internal spid hogging tempdb

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, tempdb, database-internals, service-broker

We've recently decommissioned a rather badly implemented service broker setup after a number of near outages, however while doing my morning checks I've noticed that there are 2 Service Broker internal SPIDs (<50) which are still holding ~75% of TempDB space.

Now, I know these are service broker tasks because the CMD column on SysProcesses shows 'BRKR EVENT HNDLR' and 'BRKR TASK', while the last wait types are 'BROKER_EVENTHANDLER' and 'SLEEP_TASK' respectively.  Both have 'BACKGROUND' as a status, 0 open trans and a last batch time of over a month ago.

Currently the service broker implementation has been fully disabled (from a code perspective), the queues are disabled (is_activation_enabled and is_receive_enabled = 0), there is nothing in the transmission_queue, conversation_endpoints or actual queues, but the database in question does still have is_broker_enabled = 1 (as do TempDB and MSDB).

The server is currently running SP2 with a security fix (11.0.5343.0) and the TempDB usage appears to persist even after a cluster failover.  We've not tried restarting as this is a production system, but I would have thought that a failover would have had the same effect.

Has anyone encountered this issue previously and if so, what did you do to resolve it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/264182/22336), have a look at which databases have service broker enabled (on both target and source servers)

you can use the following query to check which databases have the broker enabled:

```
--=====================================================================
-- checking what we have and where we point to
--=====================================================================
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
-- my_target_server

USE [master]
GO
SELECT   [name]
 ,[is_broker_enabled] 
 ,[service_broker_guid]
FROM [sys].[databases] 
WHERE 1=1
  AND is_broker_enabled = 1
ORDER BY  NAME
GO

SELECT name,is_broker_enabled,service_broker_guid,
is_db_chaining_on,  is_trustworthy_on FROM sys.databases
    order by 2 desc, 3 desc,  1
```

I see you mention the security update and [patching](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/219206/22336) - well done for applying it!

Depending on the environment we sometimes use [db chaining ownership on](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/20101/22336), and some times trustworthy on, instead of [module signing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81000/22336) which is the [best way in most cases](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/12/30/please-please-please-stop-using-impersonation-execute-as/).

[image]

anyway, if you are not using the broker, please switch of all of these features for each database, i.e. disable the broker, and switch it off trustworthy and db ownership chain.

--one of my examples of enabling some of these features and renewing the broker id:

```
  ALTER DATABASE ORCASTG SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE  
  ALTER DATABASE ORCASTG SET NEW_BROKER with rollback immediate
  ALTER DATABASE ORCASTG SET trustworthy on with rollback immediate
```

You want something like these (provided you are not using any of these features):

```
  USE MASTER 
  ALTER DATABASE [APCore] SET DISABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK  IMMEDIATE  
  ALTER DATABASE [APCore] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
  ALTER DATABASE [APCore] SET DB_CHAINING OFF WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

and keep [monitoring](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/189791/22336) the tempdb usage, I don't think you need neither to restart the service, nor do a failover.

In any case if you are on [alwaysOn - Availability Group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/164440/22336) you may need to remove the database from the availability group before you can disable the broker.