# what is a safe way to stop the logreader?

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication, virtualisation, patching

Applying cumulative updates and service packs on sql server 2016 -

The server is involved in [transactional replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-2017), being a publisher,

The server is [also a virtual machine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/219206/when-applying-a-sql-server-cumulative-update-or-service-pack-on-a-virtual-machin).

I need to stop the `logreader` application in order to carry on with the updates.

what could be a safe way to get this done?

[image]

Comment: Just stop the job. But I just ignore the "check files in use" page and then restart the server after the updates are done.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing that too, however, our of 12 servers, [1 got corrupted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/219258/error-code-3417-after-installing-cu-for-sql-server-2016-sp1) and it kep me thinking, had I stopped all services and applications would it have corrupted? But actually that server had not been patched for a while and had excess patching for one shot, I am tending to blame that for the unfortunate event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the log reader agent job in sql server agent. It is used by publications that are involved in t-rep. It basically copies the transactions marked for replication from the transaction log into the distribution database. Should be safe to stop it.